# Extending Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm trying to create a wrapper around [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com), to provide some additional features.  I've tried doing the following and although the constructor works, the loadData function doesn't seem to get overridden.  Any advice?

I've tested this in Chrome 45.0.2454.101m.

```
"use strict";

class CustomHandsontable extends Handsontable {

    constructor(container, options) {
        console.log("in constructor");
        super(container, options);
    }

    loadData(data) {
        console.log("load data");
        super.loadData(data);
    }
}
```

EDIT: After reading that Chrome doesn't yet fully support ECMA6, I've tried the following, but can't quite figure out how to call the parent loadData method.

```
function CustomHandsontable (container, options) {
    console.log("constructor");

    this.loadData = function(data) {
        console.log("loadData");
        // TODO how do you call the parent load data function?
    }
};

CustomHandsontable.prototype = Object.create(Handsontable.prototype);
CustomHandsontable.prototype.constructor = CustomHandsontable;
```

EDIT: Following @ZekeDroids tip to use Babel,  I get the following error when its attempting to call the super classes loadData function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

[Babel code](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Hot%20extends%20Handsontable%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(localOptions%2C%20container%2C%20options)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22in%20constructor%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(container%2C%20options)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20loadData(data)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22load%20data%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.loadData(data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

var _get = function get(_x, _x2, _x3) { var _again = true; _function: while (_again) { var object = _x, property = _x2, receiver = _x3; desc = parent = getter = undefined; _again = false; if (object === null) object = Function.prototype; var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property); if (desc === undefined) { var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); if (parent === null) { return undefined; } else { _x = parent; _x2 = property; _x3 = receiver; _again = true; continue _function; } } else if ("value" in desc) { return desc.value; } else { var getter = desc.get; if (getter === undefined) { return undefined; } return getter.call(receiver); } } };

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var Hot = (function (_Handsontable) {
    _inherits(Hot, _Handsontable);

    function Hot(localOptions, container, options) {
        _classCallCheck(this, Hot);

        console.log("in constructor");
        _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(Hot.prototype), "constructor", this).call(this, container, options);
    }

    _createClass(Hot, [{
        key: "loadData",
        value: function loadData(data) {
            console.log("load data");
            _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(Hot.prototype), "loadData", this).call(this, data);
        }
    }]);

    return Hot;
})(Handsontable);
```

Comment: Have you tried using Babel to transpile your ES6 code into ES5? It's a fairly standard way to write code nowadays. It would be advisable since Handsontable already adopted ES6 and ES7 coding convetions.

Comment: @ZekeDroid: Thanks for the tip on Babel.  I tried it out, but get an error (see my updated post).

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what to make of that. Just curious, do you really need to extend Handsontable? You can read their documentation on how to create custom builds, otherwise, I've found that there are almost no cases where normal data manipulations and JS don't serve their purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I wasn't able to get inheritance to work, but did find a solution using composition:

```
function Hot(container, options, customOptions) {
    var _instance = this;

    // create a hot instance
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, options);
    hot._hotContainer = this;

    //
    // put any custom stuff here...
    //

    //
    // since inheritance doesn't quite work, the following are all pass-through
    // functions to cover the fact that composition is being used
    //

    this.loadData = function(data) {
        hot.loadData.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    this.render = function() {
        hot.render.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    this.getDataAtRow = function() {
        return hot.getDataAtRow.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    this.countCols = function() {
        return hot.countCols.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    this.sort = function() {
        hot.sort.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```